# Edit the contents of directory tables (Linux)

Tags: linux, vim

How can I edit the contents of a directory file? Since directories are just special files with a table of links to the files contained within, I should be able to view the table right?

When I open a directory in vim I can't go into insert mode to edit the links, which I assumed would be the basic available functionality, even if it didn't work.

Comment: At the OS level, it is not possible to directly `read()` or `write()` raw bytes to and from directories.  Instead, directories use a number of specialized system calls such as `link()` and `unlink()`.  I would not find it surprising if Vim lacked support for editing directories in this fashion.

Comment: Fantastic, this is exactly what I was trying. Vim was obviously not going to open it as an editable file. So I tried to open() it and was getting nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Kevin said, you can't do it. What you CAN do is see symlinks and hardlinks with `find`, and I suppose use the `ln` command to do what you want from there.

### Using the find command

You can see all normal files with this command...

```
find <DIR> -type f -links 1
```

You can see hardlinked files with this command...

```
find <DIR> -type f -links +1
```

To see all symlinks, you could use...

```
find <DIR> -type l
```

You can add `-ls` to any of these to get a more verbose output.

Finding all symlinks in current directory, non-recursively, with additional file info:

```
find . -type l -maxdepth 1 -ls
```

### Using ln and unlink commands

Use `ln` to create links...

```
ln <current_file> <link_filename>
```

...and for symlinks...

```
ln -s <current_file> <shortcut_filename>
```

..and of course to delete a hardlink, use `rm` as usual...

```
rm <hard_link_filename>
```

...and for deleting a symlink....

```
unlink <symlink_filename>
```

Note: if the symlink links to a directory, be sure not to include a final "/"

This will not work.... `unlink /var/www/deleteme/` if `deleteme` is a directory on the other end.

Hope this helps.